# Does stationarity of AR(p) imply innovations are i.i.d.?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series, stationary-processes

Note: I have previously asked this on CrossValidated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279768/does-stationarity-of-arp-imply-innovations-are-i-i-d). Since I didn't get an answer to my question I'm posting it on this community.

My lecture notes on time series analysis give the following definition:

A stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is called **autoregressive** of order $p$ if it satisfies: $$X_t=\phi_1X_{t-1}+...+\phi_{t-p}X_{t-p}+W_t.$$ Where $W_t$ is independent from $(X_s)_{s<t}$, and $\phi_p \neq 0$.

Then it is stated that if the process is [weak-sense stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity) it follows that the $W_t$'s are identically distributed. How does this follow? Or, if incorrect, could you give me a counterexample?

Comment: If $X$ is stationary in the weak-sense, $$X_t-\phi_1X_{t-1}-\cdots-\phi_{t-p}X_{t-p}$$ has the same distributon for every $t$. Use this for $t$ and $t-1$. Independence is another matter...

Comment: How exactly does it follow that $$X_t-\phi_1X_{t-1}-...-\phi_{t-p}X_{t-p}$$ has the same distribution for every $t$?

Comment: Because $$Y_t=(X_t,X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{t-p})$$ has the same joint distribution for every $t$ and $$W_t=Y_t\cdot C$$ for some fixed column vector $C$.

Comment: @Did isn't this strongly stationary?

Comment: @Did to be clear, our definition of weak-sense stationarity only asks for the first moment and covariance to be time-invariant.

Comment: Then there is no chance that the random variables $(W_t)$ are identically distributed (for example $(W_t)$ alternatively standard normal and standard Bernoulli could not be distinguished from all standard normal).